# Glassfish fails to start

Tags: java, glassfish, asadmin

So I am trying to restart glassfish server but it fails to start. What could be the error?

`asadmin> start-domain
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.open(FileHandler.java:173)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:441)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:287)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:178)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:205)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.MultimodeCommand.executeCommands(MultimodeCommand.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.MultimodeCommand.executeCommand(MultimodeCommand.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:238)
Waiting for domain1 to start ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................`

Anyone kindly advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by "Permission denied" error you got, try one of the following:

1) Give write permissions on the directory with Glassfish to your Linux user

2) Start asadmin with sudo command

Comment: Please think twice before running a process as root to get around a permission problem.

Comment: @DanArmstrong I am very aware of risks of using `sudo` command. Note however that if admin didn't give permissions on certain directory to the user, the only way for user to access it is by using `sudo`. More important, admin is responsible for taking care about the list of sudoers.

Answer (score 1):

It obviously fails to create or open the log file:

`/home/ubuntu/glassfish-3.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log`

You should ensure that the folder structure exists and is accessible by the process (and it's user).